# How to show admob Banner in Tabbed-Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

I am showing **4 tabbed fragments with a pager view**.
I want to **show a banner ad at the bottom** when every tab changes.
Also I have multiple Fragments in my Navigation drawer.
**I also want to show banner ads when I open any of the fragment from the navigation drawer.**
I am using **Recycler View** in fragments and **Showing List of Objects** in every fragment.
I have added the admob ads dependcies, added code in the manifest.
I just want to know where should the **adView** be placed to show the banner in every fragment whether its in the tabs or a standalone fragment.

**xml of MainActivity**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
    app:title="Drawer With Swipe Tabs" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconTint="#fbc500"
        app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout></LinearLayout>
```

**Tab Frament**
This Controls all the tabbed activity.

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

  public static TabLayout tabLayout;
  public static ViewPager viewPager;
  public static int int_items = 4;

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int_items - 1);

    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
      }
    });

    return x;

  }

  class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      switch (position) {
        case 0:
          return new Fragment1();
        case 1:
          return new Fragment2();
        case 2:
          return new Fragment3();
        case 3:
          return new Fragment4();
      }
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return int_items;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

      switch (position) {
        case 0:
          return "Tab1";
        case 1:
          return "Tab2";
        case 2:
          return "Tab3";
        case 3:
          return "Tab4";
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**xml Tablayout**
This holds the ids for view pager and tabs

```
< LinearLayout
xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns: app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: orientation = "vertical"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content" >

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android: id = "@+id/tabs"
app: tabGravity = "center"
app: tabMode = "scrollable"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content" >
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android: id = "@+id/viewpager"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

All of the Fragments Activities are like this
**Fragment Activity**

```
public class TopNewsFragment extends Fragment {
  public TopNewsFragment() {}
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cheese_list, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity());
    recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList < Values > ());

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);


    return rootView;
  }
```

And Last the Fragment Layout:
**fragment_cheese_list**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this `XML` code with your existing.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/containerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemIconTint="#fbc500"
    app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:menu="@menu/drawermenu" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by editing fragment_cheese_list.xml like this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="55dp" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```